# How to embed viewerjs in an angular app

Tags: angular, angular-cli, viewer

I would like to make use of http://viewerjs.org in an angular 4 app using angular-cli to preview documents within the app. I have tried placing the viewerjs folder in the src root folder and assets folder, but unable to get the page to load. I would appreciate every help I can get in figuring this out.

Answer (score -3):

Remember your working in the Angular world now not a normal web site environment. It looks like they don't offer an Angular version. You will need that in order to be able to use it.